# using % (modulus) to set variables in Java

Tags: java, setvalue

I'm trying to work with % (modulus operator), where I have a number which is for example 1215 and I want to change it with "x" number so it shows x15..

I was thinking on doing the following

```
x= 10;//(for example)
time = 1215;

settime = (time/100)%100;//(it's gonna get rid of the 15 and grab the 12)

settime= x;

//Now I'm stock in this part on how to set that to the time without changing the minutes("15")
//so it desplays 1015?
```

Comment: Just so you know, it would return `15`, not `12`.  But I believe you could just add `x * 100` to it?

Comment: @Pokechu22 but okay if I do multiplication how am i gonna set the x value to that settime variable then passing it to time with out changing the entire variable of time to x?

Comment: `time = (x * 100) + (time % 100)`?

Comment: @DavidConrad it's didn't work man!,any other ideas?